# How to break `with_lines` cycle in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I would like to use the following handler with Ansible:

```
- name: force ntp update
  shell: ntpdate {{item}}
  with_lines: /etc/ntpd.serverlist
```

But I want it to end execution after the first successful execution (the list contains ntpd servers with which you can attempt to sync. One is enough). How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very interesting situation you have. I haven't tried this personally, but I wonder if something like this would work:

```
- name: force ntp update
  shell: ntpdate {{item}}
  with_lines: /etc/ntpd.serverlist
  register: ntp_result
  when: ntp_result is not defined or ntp_result.rc != 0
  ignore_errors: yes
```

So in a nutshell, each call to ntpdate should populate the `ntp_result` variable with the return code of the call to `ntpdate`. The `when` clause then ensures the loop continues if the variable doesn't exist (as it wouldn't have been populated during the first iteration), or if the `ntpdate` call failed (rc != 0). Telling Ansible to ignore any errors ensures that it continues looping if any of the calls to `ntpdate` does return an error.

The only real downside to this is that it won't directly notify you if none of the calls to `ntpdate` succeed.  However you can probably follow this task with something along the lines of:

```
- name: fail if ntpdate fails
  fail: msg="All calls to ntpdate failed"
  when: ntp_result.rc != 0
```

If the last call resulted in a non-zero result from `ntpdate` then it means none of them succeeded.

Comment: I thought about something like this, but is `with_lines` counted as a cycle and as a subject to `when` condition?

Comment: Yes, it is.  From the [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement): "Note that when combining when with with_items (see Loops), be aware that the when statement is processed separately for each item. This is by design."

Comment: Can't I replace that complex `when` with `until: result|success`?

Answer (score 4):

At least on Ansible 2.2.1.0 a `when` statement can break the loop, and the following works skipping all evaluations after the first success:

```
---
# test.yml

# run this playbook with: ansible-playbook -i localhost, test.yml

- hosts: localhost
connection: local
gather_facts: no
tasks:
  - name: check
    shell: "[ {{item}} -ne 2 ]"
    register: checks
    ignore_errors: yes
    changed_when: false
    when: checks is not defined or checks.rc != 0
    with_items: [2,3,2,4]
  - name: set
    set_fact: first_working={{ item.item }}
    when: "'rc' in item and item.rc == 0"
    with_items: "{{ checks.results }}"
  - debug: var=first_working
  # Note that first_working will be undefined if no check succeeded
```

This is the output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [check] *******************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item=2) => {"changed": false, "cmd": "[ 2 -ne 2 ]", "delta": "0:00:00.001735", "end": "2017-03-13 16:14:00.515372", "failed": true, "item": 2, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-03-13 16:14:00.513637", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
ok: [localhost] => (item=3)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=4)
...ignoring

TASK [set] *********************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'_ansible_parsed': True, u'cmd': u'[ 2 -ne 2 ]', u'end': u'2017-03-13 16:14:00.515372', '_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout': u'', '_ansible_item_result': True, u'changed': False, 'item': 2, u'delta': u'0:00:00.001735', u'stderr': u'', u'rc': 1, 'invocation': {'module_name': u'command', u'module_args': {u'creates': None, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'[ 2 -ne 2 ]', u'removes': None, u'warn': True, u'chdir': None}}, 'stdout_lines': [], u'start': u'2017-03-13 16:14:00.513637', u'warnings': [], 'failed': True})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'_ansible_parsed': True, u'changed': False, u'stdout': u'', '_ansible_no_log': False, u'warnings': [], '_ansible_item_result': True, u'rc': 0, u'end': u'2017-03-13 16:14:00.615658', u'start': u'2017-03-13 16:14:00.613978', u'cmd': u'[ 3 -ne 2 ]', 'item': 3, u'delta': u'0:00:00.001680', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'command', u'module_args': {u'creates': None, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'[ 3 -ne 2 ]', u'removes': None, u'warn': True, u'chdir': None}}, 'stdout_lines': [], u'stderr': u''})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'skipped': True, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional check failed', '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': 2, 'changed': False})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'skipped': True, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional check failed', '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': 4, 'changed': False})

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "first_working": "3"
}
```

Comment: @techraf yes I have tried. I guess this is related to how Ansible stores `checks` during the loops. The behaviour is different in both mentioned versions of Ansible. In Ansible 2.2.1.0, the execution stops after the first successful. In 1.9.6 it doesn't. Sorry for the typos that I have corrected.

Comment: @techraf I'm not sure about the old example on version 1.9.6, but I have revised and corrected the answer for the current Ansible version 2.2.1.0

Comment: Now it's a very good (and more importantly: true, as opposed to invented-and-not-tested) answer.